# using paging in DataTable for showing in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I want 30 data in GridView. I want to read all the files in my folder and show in GridView. I am using the following code.

```
string folderPath = @"C:\Folder\Folder-2.0\New folder";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
//Creating DataTable

foreach (string fileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.txt"))
    {
        string contents = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
        string str = string.Empty;
        string s;

        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
            String line;               
            int k = 0;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] text;

                if (line.Trim() != string.Empty)
                {
                    //text = line.Split(new char[] { '^' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    text = line.Split('^');

                    if (text[0].Contains("START FOOTER"))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DataRow dr;
                        dr = dt.NewRow();

                        for (int i = 0; i <= text.Length - 1; i++)
                        {
                            dr[i] = text[i];
                        }

                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        k = k + 1;
                    }
                }

            }
            Response.Write(k);
            //  Response.End;
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
        else
        {
            s = "File does not exists";
        }
    }
```

But the above Code throws error `System.OutOfMemoryException`. Error is pointing at code `GridView1.DataBind();` There are about 2000 files in the folder each file is of size between 1 to 2 MB. Thats why I want to use paging using DataTable. Through DataTable I want to show 30 records.

Thanks,

Comment: i think you need to refactor your method and try to use indexed page loop and save the last index. I am not sure thats the error you might need to init your `DataTable` with a `DataColumn`

Comment: Whats paging gonna do alone, you need to bind only few records at a time, then maintain the index and deal with it

Answer (score 0):

Please define PageSize as 30 and implement PageIndexChanging event

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridView1PageEventArgs e)
{
    // here you need create one method of your above code and call here 
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't  want this paging I want to do paging in DataTable i.e. call first 30 records from datatable then next 30. I don't want to load whole datatable at once.

Comment: @rahulaggarwal I would like to suggest you to add on Id column as numeric field and increment as per record and user Select Method of DataTable ie. DataTable.Select("ID=> 1 AND ID<=30)

Comment: I think you need to use Take() and Skip() Method of Directory.EnumerateFiles().